# How to append to a large YAML file that has multiple keys

Tags: ruby, append, yaml

I have a very large YAML file, and I need to append to certain keys within the file itself. (I'll give about half of the values and keys but all the YAML):

```
md5:
  0db1af356a757d7e6141de9e0509b6c0: aspherical,
  cc582c8a08d9983c4cabbf4db79346d6: aledo,
  ffb013ac241e53910c0babbe5fc27928: aet,
  4fa28fa73a7577c68dddb9cbf337680e: aglisten,
  c7ead5d7e7d7fbbee16c49e398fc335d: assessable,
  61ea1a1a2645db7442479a0c23dc9e27: amaranthaceous,
  f447b20a7fcbf53a5d5be013ea0b15af: 123456,
  286755fad04869ca523320acce0dc6a4: password,
  d577273ff885c3f84dadb8578bb41399: 12345,
  23cdc18507b52418db7740cbb5543e54: 12345678,
  a86850deb2742ec3cb41518e26aa2d89: qwerty,
  b2cfa4183267af678ea06c7407d4d6d8: 123456789,
  e7df7cd2ca07f4f1ab415d457a6e1c13: 1234,
  5b9d07ad9c1bed09d6986e593f4ca7dc: baseball,
  c0ce0dff9996a7d40c1e96a944dd0fc5: dragon,
  a174fdeed30655297c43208a716875b3: football,
  1b504d3328e16fdf281d1fb9516dd90b: 1234567,
  2f548f61bd37f628077e552ae1537be2: monkey,
  4aacf9c858c82716ab0034320bd2efe9: letmein,
  2c6c8ab6ba8b9c98a1939450eb4089ed: abc123,
  77a319564621b96fa0656e24c67960ef: 111111,
  d3c3ce1b8b4e88e23a04a1f123eeb593: mustang,
  a56ffd9f01fa749377cbaea011a57365: access,
  54bad4757ad046d8e4e762aea1e022a7: shadow,
  c963080767f45828c31f83ca5cd25d36: master,
  3a8c088f9cfe9a0a564fe3fbb277263a: michael
sha256:
  d47ac74b773ffff504ede166b4d62a575ae2beccd7966dbee33f26ff84114d8f: aspherical,
  978b54c60b0e86b1b51019bb5c88f92fb381c7145f600dbb1280d96398f5feea: aledo,
  c3236dd164056aa319b58d07a1e1c0bc5815dc39783981b19fabfa92714c18ba: aet,
  d5375b39c5a773f55a33d71507d6080014f5fd302032ec62de03a2a56c33707b: aglisten,
  88cca75f4214587a63f468855b1e942495bb5390467e543a4a28f636753d9262: assessable,
  2defadb0da568c52e952ae495368840d42a4ebe849ab47150f6807e086ab28e2: amaranthaceous,
  e150a1ec81e8e93e1eae2c3a77e66ec6dbd6a3b460f89c1d08aecf422ee401a0: 123456,
  6b3a55e0261b0304143f805a24924d0c1c44524821305f31d9277843b8a10f4e: password,
  f33ae3bc9a22cd7564990a794789954409977013966fb1a8f43c35776b833a95: 12345,
  2634c3097f98e36865f0c572009c4ffd73316bc8b88ccfe8d196af35f46e2394: 12345678,
  9ceece10cf8b97d1f1924dae5d14c137fd144ce999ede85f48be6d7582e2dd23: qwerty,
  6d78392a5886177fe5b86e585a0b695a2bcd01a05504b3c4e38bc8eeb21e8326: 123456789,
  a883dafc480d466ee04e0d6da986bd78eb1fdd2178d04693723da3a8f95d42f4: 1234,
  e11184da809af8dca98d471082647632fd954d674913e41d2e7aed93d2d224c7: baseball,
  24e11938b9091b4dbc66a5e5b4705834e5e738fa85a80cd5f8844d976026b49e: dragon,
  205b60ee79914af6a09b897170b522c5e16366214b9a0735b4eb550f4b14a3c8: football,
  349abe1272178917136372f667b13753e2c775bbe39112118420b7697749c97b: 1234567,
  5a6e48105fea75ccccc66a038318f398c42761495d738786dc8a6d43179aa16a: monkey,
  8de47d5aa7d61e92c577d8156b966583f6d7d75d714a3b99fca4fb2f8bfe97c6: letmein,
  5ecf8d2cc410094e8b82dd0bc178a57f3aa1e80916689beb00fe56148b1b1256: abc123,
  9d272f1f3e92f7c5efdcfdda0ab92facccd98c340be8be09064060503fd167e4: 111111,
  aeb3e1c05ceed52c929eb539b0d45ffb12ecc68881ca28a634d9e02ff49225e9: mustang,
  74a53d5ef93d260701dee7ef8ae4957d363a299d9e8a195cbd87ab63ffb4d0e4: access,
  36c8168624b0b6e3a623e064b82730af1c30c1dae97ab260237a800c39707941: shadow,
  9b3162498c21d7f960877099174ecea13410bd21d12440b2ea8868117fc08ae0: master,
  bb472c3cc2b662a74956c8539fec9fe73f2b8a9f9124506aa0474698b3bac62d: michael,
  f4b0726157bf8b1aab7b74cfe5195fd2c2d5b11ad8902e545de460fe1217e3fa: superman
sha1:
  21bb0c84ecc88629788314747337af2d4c3d6a4f: aspherical,
  aee0161f2d7168beac985db5cfda43ac959e053b: aledo,
  73a2bd0d315aaef2b90ee4de15ab4a34e048703a: aet,
  591b6b8a007ac1c67be430bb6431adbaab930538: aglisten,
  c1ad62f7db7beff07353b0d42e685dec6ef12f4e: assessable,
  c689373a119b17a512782682df48d85e47a4e9de: amaranthaceous,
  c4f9375f9834b4e7f0a528cc65c055702bf5f24a: 123456,
  c8fed00eb2e87f1cee8e90ebbe870c190ac3848c: password,
  2672275fe0c456fb671e4f417fb2f9892c7573ba: 12345,
  9806af3952e1380212b0998f07a6afe4e5f00428: 12345678,
  3c8b9f4b983afa9f644d26e2b34fa3e03a2bef16: qwerty,
  179c94cf45c6e383baf52621687305204cef16f9: 123456789,
  1be168ff837f043bde17c0314341c84271047b31: 1234,
  e1f48cd1226e4ce7ab8bf87d15ce7c9b0014cf16: baseball,
  8851def7166796964bf58174a5f3f50d073d709d: dragon,
  3516c253ea583fe2c60e983c7b8bc9075aedd161: football,
  e017693e4a04a59d0b0f400fe98177fe7ee13cf7: 1234567,
  744a9a056f145b86339221bb457aa57129f55bc2: monkey,
  34ca062314edaa193e03f318ae20ae134274b358: letmein,
  61ee8b5601a84d5154387578466c8998848ba089: abc123,
  3ee88a74d3722b336a69c428d226f731435c71ba: 111111,
  059a9d50d1155bb31ad65df3e0cfb20c8f98894b: mustang,
  65b9b171f2173eccc48c8764f91a8bcc1b586c4f: access
sha2:
  d47ac74b773ffff504ede166b4d62a575ae2beccd7966dbee33f26ff84114d8f: aspherical,
  978b54c60b0e86b1b51019bb5c88f92fb381c7145f600dbb1280d96398f5feea: aledo,
  c3236dd164056aa319b58d07a1e1c0bc5815dc39783981b19fabfa92714c18ba: aet,
  d5375b39c5a773f55a33d71507d6080014f5fd302032ec62de03a2a56c33707b: aglisten,
  88cca75f4214587a63f468855b1e942495bb5390467e543a4a28f636753d9262: assessable,
  2defadb0da568c52e952ae495368840d42a4ebe849ab47150f6807e086ab28e2: amaranthaceous,
  e150a1ec81e8e93e1eae2c3a77e66ec6dbd6a3b460f89c1d08aecf422ee401a0: 123456,
  6b3a55e0261b0304143f805a24924d0c1c44524821305f31d9277843b8a10f4e: password,
  f33ae3bc9a22cd7564990a794789954409977013966fb1a8f43c35776b833a95: 12345,
  2634c3097f98e36865f0c572009c4ffd73316bc8b88ccfe8d196af35f46e2394: 12345678,
  9ceece10cf8b97d1f1924dae5d14c137fd144ce999ede85f48be6d7582e2dd23: qwerty,
  6d78392a5886177fe5b86e585a0b695a2bcd01a05504b3c4e38bc8eeb21e8326: 123456789,
  a883dafc480d466ee04e0d6da986bd78eb1fdd2178d04693723da3a8f95d42f4: 1234,
  e11184da809af8dca98d471082647632fd954d674913e41d2e7aed93d2d224c7: baseball,
  24e11938b9091b4dbc66a5e5b4705834e5e738fa85a80cd5f8844d976026b49e: dragon,
  205b60ee79914af6a09b897170b522c5e16366214b9a0735b4eb550f4b14a3c8: football,
  349abe1272178917136372f667b13753e2c775bbe39112118420b7697749c97b: 1234567,
  5a6e48105fea75ccccc66a038318f398c42761495d738786dc8a6d43179aa16a: monkey,
  8de47d5aa7d61e92c577d8156b966583f6d7d75d714a3b99fca4fb2f8bfe97c6: letmein,
  5ecf8d2cc410094e8b82dd0bc178a57f3aa1e80916689beb00fe56148b1b1256: abc123,
  9d272f1f3e92f7c5efdcfdda0ab92facccd98c340be8be09064060503fd167e4: 111111
```

I want to append to the `sha256` hash within the YAML file. How can I go about appending to that part of the file, without appending to any other parts of the file?

I tried:

```
def add_to(hash, type, word)
  type[hash] = word
  File.open('./lib/list/rainbow_table.yml', 'a+'){ |s| YAML.dump(type, s) }
end #<= Outputs error: "rainbow.rb:67:in `[]='"
```

How can I go about this without erasing the file, or getting an error, and appending to that one aspect?

Comment: Please quantify "very large". Would that be megabytes? Gigabytes? Can it all be loaded into memory at once?

Comment: @Raffael I'm working on this project with this guy, no it can not, it'll crash your system. It has a total of 24224 lines.

Comment: Hmm, 25'000 lines at 80 characters per line amount to a total of around 4 MB of data. That certainly would not exceed the RAM of my machine :) Please state the size of your file in bytes / megabytes / gigabytes.

Comment: @Raffael As of right now it's 1.41mb, however it will grow is the problem and the goal is not to screw anyone by eating a bunch of RAM

Comment: Consider splitting the data up into multiple files. One per type. Each file now only contains a list of key-value pairs, one per line. Appending an entry to the correct type will be as easy as appending a line to the correct file. Trivial! :) These files can be YAML but could also be an even simpler format, e.g. CSV.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing is to load the file into memory using YAML. You'll get a hash of hashes. Modify the hash in question, then rewrite the file.

For instance:

```
require 'yaml'

data = YAML.load(<<EOT)
md5:
  0db1af356a757d7e6141de9e0509b6c0: aspherical,
sha256:
  d47ac74b773ffff504ede166b4d62a575ae2beccd7966dbee33f26ff84114d8f: aspherical,
sha1:
  21bb0c84ecc88629788314747337af2d4c3d6a4f: aspherical,
sha2:
  d47ac74b773ffff504ede166b4d62a575ae2beccd7966dbee33f26ff84114d8f: aspherical,
EOT

md5 = data['md5']
md5['another_key'] = 'foo'
md5['some_other_key'] = 'bar'

data['md5'] = md5
puts data.to_yaml

# >> ---
# >> md5:
# >>   0db1af356a757d7e6141de9e0509b6c0: "\uFEFFaspherical,"
# >>   another_key: foo
# >>   some_other_key: bar
# >> sha256:
# >>   d47ac74b773ffff504ede166b4d62a575ae2beccd7966dbee33f26ff84114d8f: "\uFEFFaspherical,"
# >> sha1:
# >>   21bb0c84ecc88629788314747337af2d4c3d6a4f: "\uFEFFaspherical,"
# >> sha2:
# >>   d47ac74b773ffff504ede166b4d62a575ae2beccd7966dbee33f26ff84114d8f: "\uFEFFaspherical,"
```

You'll want to make sure you practice safe file updating to avoid destroying the old file but that's a different question.

You *could* walk through the file, reading lines to locate the appropriate section, insert lines, then continue walking through the rest of the file. Every line from the original file would have to be written to the output file. It's more work but isn't difficult code to write, however, unless the YAML file won't fit into memory, I'd use the above concept.

---

```
File.open('./lib/list/rainbow_table.yml', 'a+'){ |s| YAML.dump(type, s) }
```

You don't want to append to a YAML file like that. YAML is structured data, either a hash or an array, so you have to maintain the appropriate structure, which appending won't do. You *can* have multiple YAML documents in one file, but it'll result in a confusing file and still won't give you what you want when you're finished. Reading then rewriting the file will help keep it more organized.

Use something like:

```
File.write('path/to/file.yaml', some_array_or_hash.to_yaml)
```

Don't make it more complicated using `open` to append. You can't cleanly append to the YAML file and maintain the objects, so don't use `'a'`. Overwrite the file and generate a clean object.

It'd help you to read [the YAML specification](http://yaml.org), especially the part about multiple documents in a file, then to experiment with different ideas. I think you'll find that appending will break your object.

Meditate on this:

```
require 'yaml'

obj1 = {
  'a' => {
    'foo' => ['something']
  }
}

obj1 # => {"a"=>{"foo"=>["something"]}}

obj1.to_yaml # => "---\na:\n  foo:\n  - something\n"

YAML.load(obj1.to_yaml) 
# => {"a"=>{"foo"=>["something"]}}
```

That demonstrates creating an object, serializing it and parsing the serialized output to get the object back.

---

Here's a more gentle approach to the problem.

This seems to be what you are trying to do:

```
obj2 = {
  'a' => {
    'bar' => ['something else']
  }
}

output_file = obj1.to_yaml
# => "---\na:\n  foo:\n  - something\n"
```

At this point you have an YAML file.

You want to append to it, resulting in a file containing two YAML documents:

```
output_file += obj2.to_yaml
# => "---\na:\n  foo:\n  - something\n---\na:\n  bar:\n  - something else\n"
```

When you reload the file in you're overwriting the initial `'a'` key/value pair because a hash can only have unique keys, and the first `'a'` will be overwritten by any attempt to read it in a subsequent part of the file:

```
YAML.load(output_file)
# => {"a"=>{"foo"=>["something"]}}
```

YAML supports loading all documents in a file, however they're parsed into an array of objects:

```
YAML.load_stream(output_file)
# => [{"a"=>{"foo"=>["something"]}}, {"a"=>{"bar"=>["something else"]}}]
```

You'd have to walk through that array every time you read or alter the file and reconstruct the original object, which will take longer and longer and will be prone to errors.

Instead of doing that, if you read the original file in using `load_file` you'll have it in memory. Then you can append to the section you want:

```
obj1['a']['bar'] = ['something else']
obj1 
# => {"a"=>{"foo"=>["something"], "bar"=>["something else"]}}
```

You can write that modified data back to the file:

```
output_file = obj1.to_yaml 
# => "---\na:\n  foo:\n  - something\n  bar:\n  - something else\n"
```

And correctly reload it later. Again, use `load_file`, not `load` as I'm using here, to read the YAML data from the file.

```
YAML.load(output_file) 
# => {"a"=>{"foo"=>["something"], "bar"=>["something else"]}}
```

Finding documentation for [YAML](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/index.html) in Ruby involves reading the YAML class documentation, along with [the Psych documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/psych/rdoc/index.html). Several years ago Psych was introduced to speed up YAML processing.

And, just as a sidebar, Psych/YAML can read/parse JSON data, as JSON is a subset of YAML:

```
YAML.load('{"foo": "bar"}')
# => {"foo"=>"bar"}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example please? The guy I'm working with used a ten minute email to create an account and now can't log back in..

Comment: That makes sense, so basically slurping it into memory is the easiest way other than editing as is? Why is that?

Comment: How would you write it back to the file? `File.open('test.yml', 'a'){ |f| f.puts(data.to_yaml)}`?

Comment: When I've been attempting to write the the file I've been getting `rainbow.rb:55:in `[]=': string not matched (IndexError); from rainbow.rb:55:in `add_to_rainbow'; from rainbow.rb:71:in `<main>'` as an error, I'm not sure what this means, any insite?

Comment: Absolutely none. I don't have access to the code. Perhaps if you hold your computer screen closer to the keyboard?